# How to cluster values based on their frequency of occurrence?

Tags: algorithm, statistics, cluster-analysis, frequency, similarity

I am working on a clustering algorithm where I need to cluster values based on their frequency in the data. This would indicate which values are not important and would be treated as the part of a larger cluster than individual entity.

I am new to data science and would like to know the best algorithm/approach to achieve this.

For example, I have the following data set. The first column are the property values and second column denotes their frequency of occurrence.

```
Value = [1, 1.5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 16, 32, 128]
Frequency = [207, 19, 169, 92, 36, 7, 12, 5, 2, 2]

Here, Frequency[i] corresponds to Value[i]
```

The frequency can be thought of as the importance of a value. The other thing which denotes the importance of a value is the distance between the elements in the array. For example, 1.5 is not that significant compared to 32 or 128, since it has elements much closer such as 1 and 2.

When approaching to cluster these values, I need to look at distances between values and also the frequency of their occurrence. A possible output for the above problem would be

```
Clust_value = [(1, 1.5), 2, 3, 4, (6, 8), 16, (32, 128)]
```

This is not the best cluster but one possible answer. I need to know the best algorithm to approach this problem.

Firstly, I tried to solve this problem without taking into account the spread of elements in the values array, but that gave wrong answers in some situations. We have tried using mean and median for clustering values again with no successful outcome.

We have tried comparing frequencies of the neighbors and then clubbing the values into one cluster. We also tried to find the minimum distance between the elements of the values array and then putting them into one cluster if their difference was greater than a threshold value, but this failed to cluster values if they had low frequencies. I also looked for clustering algorithms on-line but did not get any useful resource relevant to the problem defined above.

Is there any better way to approach the problem?

Comment: `This is not the best cluster but one possible answer.` - the problem does not seem to be very well defined. E.g. why is clustering 32, 128 here but leaving 16 on its own better than e.g. clustering 16 and 32? - `that gave wrong answers` - how _exactly_ do you determine what's right or wrong? For clustering on frequency alone, I might suggest something along the lines of Shannon-Fano or Huffman coding.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I have not been able to frame the problem correctly. The problem is to from cluster of values array depending on two things - their frequency and the distance between nodes. 32, 128 formed cluster to basically make a cluster of frequency 4 . If it joined with 16 the cluster frequency would have been 7 and and for 128 would be 2. Thus to achieve comparable frequencies in clusters 32 was paired with 128 and not 16, however 32 is closer to 16 than 128. Hope I am clear enough now!

Answer (score 0):

You need to come up with some mathematical quality criterion of what makes one solution better than another. Unless you have thousands of numbers, you can afford a rather 'brute force' method: begin with the first number, add the next as long as your quality increases, otherwise begin a new cluster. Because your data are *sorted* this will be fairly efficient and find a rather good solution (you can try additional splits to further improve quality).

So it all boils down to *you* needing to specify quality.

Do not assume that existing criteria (e.g. variance in k-means) work for you. At most, you may be able to find a data transformation such that your requirements turn into variance, but that also will be specific to your problem.